# How to update app locale with layout direction in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, localization

```
  Locale locale = new Locale(language);
  Locale.setDefault(locale);
  Resources res = context.getResources();
  Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
  config.locale = locale;
```

I have tried above code but it is not working on Android N but working on Pie device. How can we update the locale for all android versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to read this good article.

https://androidwave.com/android-multi-language-support-best-practices/

Thanks,
Rhen